# Postgres 'syntax error at end of input' when using recursive cte

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgresSQL with pgAdmin 4.

I'm getting a syntax error at end of input and I'm not sure where the issue is. I'm gonna drop the code below.

The efront table is in the database.

Would appreciate any help in understanding the problem :)

```
with recursive cte as (
      select e.result_data_branch_id as branch_id, e.result_data_branch_id as topBranch_id, e.result_data_branch_name as branch_name
      from efront e
      where result_data_branch_parent_id is null
      union all
      select  e.result_data_branch_id, cte.topBranch_id, cte.branch_name
      from efront e join
           cte
           on e.result_data_branch_parent_id = cte.branch_id       
     )
```

Comment: where's the statement that's following the `with` declaration?

Comment: Are you talking about the select statement?

Comment: A select, or [anything](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), yes